# Exception while inserting data in to Sqlitedatabase

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have written the code to insert the data into `SQLite` database at that time I am getting `nullpointer` exception at the line return `db.insert("userdetails", null, initialValues);`

```
public class DBUserAdapter {

            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users"; 
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 

            private static final String USERDETAILS=
                    "create table userdetails(usersno integer primary key autoincrement,photo BLOB,date text not null);";

            private Context context = null; 
            private DatabaseHelper DBHelper; 
            private SQLiteDatabase db; 


        //    public DBUserAdapter(Context ctx) {
        //        this.context = ctx; 
        //        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
        //    }


            public DBUserAdapter(SampleViewBase sampleViewBase) {

                 DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            }


            private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
            { 
                DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
                { 
                    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
                }

                public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                     db.execSQL(USERDETAILS);

                }

                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users"); 
                        onCreate(db); 
                } 

        }
             public void open() throws SQLException 
                { 
                    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
                } 

                public void close() 
                { 
                    DBHelper.close(); 
                }     

                public long insert(byte[] photo, String date) 
                { 
                     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
                     initialValues.put("photo", photo); 
                     initialValues.put("date", date); 
                    // initialValues.put(KEY_TIME, time); 
                     Log.d("inotvaluessssssssss",initialValues.toString());
                     return db.insert("userdetails", null, initialValues);

                }
```

My main Activity

```
public abstract class SampleViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "Sample-ImageManipulations::SurfaceView";
    DBUserAdapter dbUser= null ;


    private SurfaceHolder       mHolder;
    private VideoCapture        mCamera;
    byte[] photo;
    //  Mat mRgba;
    Mat mRgba = new Mat(); 
    Mat mRgba1= new Mat(); 
    // private FpsMeter            mFps;
    int[] intArray = new int[50];
//  int[] y;
//  int check=0;
    int cod=0;


    public SampleViewBase(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // mFps = new FpsMeter();
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
                                          }

    public boolean openCamera() {
        Log.i(TAG, "openCamera");
        synchronized (this) {
            releaseCamera();
            mCamera = new VideoCapture(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID);
            if (!mCamera.isOpened()) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open native camera");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void releaseCamera() {
        Log.i(TAG, "releaseCamera");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setupCamera("+width+", "+height+")");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null && mCamera.isOpened()) {
                List<Size> sizes = mCamera.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                int mFrameWidth = width;
                int mFrameHeight = height;

                // selecting optimal camera preview size
                {
                    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    for (Size size : sizes) {
                        if (Math.abs(size.height - height) < minDiff) {
                            mFrameWidth = (int) size.width;
                            mFrameHeight = (int) size.height;
                            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - height);
                        }
                    }
                }

                mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, mFrameWidth);
                mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, mFrameHeight);
            }
        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder _holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        setupCamera(width, height);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        releaseCamera();
    }

    protected abstract Bitmap processFrame(VideoCapture capture);

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
        //mFps.init();

        while (true) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            synchronized (this) {
                if (mCamera == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "mCamera == null");
                    break;
                }

                if (!mCamera.grab()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mCamera.grab() failed");
                    break;
                                   }
                 bmp = processFrame(mCamera);
                 String i1=bmp.toString();
                 dbUser = new DBUserAdapter(SampleViewBase.this);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system


                //    mRgba= (Mat)processFrame(mCamera);



                ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
                photo = blob.toByteArray();
                dbUser.insert(photo, dateTime);
                Log.d("bitmapdataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",""+photo);
                Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32,mRgba); 
                Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32,mRgba1); 
        //      Log.d("lengthhhhhhhhhhhh",""+bitmapdata.length);
                //              for(int k=0;k<bitmapdata.length;k++)
                //              {
                //                  
                //              }
                bmp = processFrame(mCamera);
                int i= bmp.getWidth();
                int j=bmp.getHeight();
                Log.d("Coming outoutttttttttttt ","Coming outputtttttttt");
                intArray=FindFeatures(mRgba1.getNativeObjAddr(),mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[0]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[1]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[2]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[3]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[3]);
            //  Log.d("Coming outo-----------------------==========","hjhjhj");
                //    mRgba=(Mat)bitmapdata;
                //  mFps.measure();
            //   Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);

            }

            if (bmp != null)
            {
                Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) 
                {
                    //Log.d("Coming outo---454545--------------------==========","hjhjhj");
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (canvas.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth()) / 2, (canvas.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight()), null);
                    // mFps.draw(canvas, (canvas.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth()) / 2, 0);

                    mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                bmp.recycle();
                }

            //FindFeatures(bitmapdata,j,i);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Finishing processing thread");
    }
    //   public native void FindFeatures(final byte[] bitmapdata,long m,int height,int width);
    public native int[] FindFeatures(long n,long m);
    static {
    //  Log.d("Coming hereeeeeee","Coming hereeeeeeeeeeeeee");
        System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");

    }

    public class Demo
    {
        int[] x;
        int[] y;
        int check=0;
        int cod=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you actually calling open() before you call insert()? I'd put a breakpoint inside of insert, and examine your variables. In Eclipse you can right click in the left side tray, choose toggle breakpoint, and click the bug icon. Then, when the point is hit, check out the value of your variables, as one isn't in a state you expect it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mainactivity, do this modification doing dbUser.open() before calling insert and doing dbUser.close() after insert is done.

This is the modification:

```
                dbUser = new DBUserAdapter(SampleViewBase.this);
                dbUser.open(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< look at this modification too
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system


                //    mRgba= (Mat)processFrame(mCamera);



                ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
                photo = blob.toByteArray();
                dbUser.insert(photo, dateTime);
                dbUser.close(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< look at this modification too
                Log.d("bitmapdataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",""+photo);
                Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

This is the MainActivity code with modifications:

```
    public abstract class SampleViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {
    private static final String TAG = "Sample-ImageManipulations::SurfaceView";
    DBUserAdapter dbUser= null ;


    private SurfaceHolder       mHolder;
    private VideoCapture        mCamera;
    private Context mContext;
    byte[] photo;
    //  Mat mRgba;
    Mat mRgba = new Mat(); 
    Mat mRgba1= new Mat(); 
    // private FpsMeter            mFps;
    int[] intArray = new int[50];
//  int[] y;
//  int check=0;
    int cod=0;


    public SampleViewBase(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // mFps = new FpsMeter();
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
                                          }

    public boolean openCamera() {
        Log.i(TAG, "openCamera");
        synchronized (this) {
            releaseCamera();
            mCamera = new VideoCapture(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID);
            if (!mCamera.isOpened()) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to open native camera");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void releaseCamera() {
        Log.i(TAG, "releaseCamera");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setupCamera("+width+", "+height+")");
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null && mCamera.isOpened()) {
                List<Size> sizes = mCamera.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
                int mFrameWidth = width;
                int mFrameHeight = height;

                // selecting optimal camera preview size
                {
                    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                    for (Size size : sizes) {
                        if (Math.abs(size.height - height) < minDiff) {
                            mFrameWidth = (int) size.width;
                            mFrameHeight = (int) size.height;
                            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - height);
                        }
                    }
                }

                mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, mFrameWidth);
                mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, mFrameHeight);
            }
        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder _holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceChanged");
        setupCamera(width, height);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
        releaseCamera();
    }

    protected abstract Bitmap processFrame(VideoCapture capture);

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
        //mFps.init();

        while (true) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            synchronized (this) {
                if (mCamera == null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "mCamera == null");
                    break;
                }

                if (!mCamera.grab()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "mCamera.grab() failed");
                    break;
                                   }
                 bmp = processFrame(mCamera);
                 String i1=bmp.toString();
                 dbUser = new DBUserAdapter(mContext);
                 dbUser.open(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< look at this modification too
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system


                //    mRgba= (Mat)processFrame(mCamera);



                ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
                photo = blob.toByteArray();
                dbUser.insert(photo, dateTime);
                dbUser.close(); // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< look at this modification too
                Log.d("bitmapdataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",""+photo);
                Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

                Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32,mRgba); 
                Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32,mRgba1); 
        //      Log.d("lengthhhhhhhhhhhh",""+bitmapdata.length);
                //              for(int k=0;k<bitmapdata.length;k++)
                //              {
                //                  
                //              }
                bmp = processFrame(mCamera);
                int i= bmp.getWidth();
                int j=bmp.getHeight();
                Log.d("Coming outoutttttttttttt ","Coming outputtttttttt");
                intArray=FindFeatures(mRgba1.getNativeObjAddr(),mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[0]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[1]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[2]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[3]);
                Log.d("valueeeeeeeeee",""+intArray[3]);
            //  Log.d("Coming outo-----------------------==========","hjhjhj");
                //    mRgba=(Mat)bitmapdata;
                //  mFps.measure();
            //   Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);

            }

            if (bmp != null)
            {
                Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
                if (canvas != null) 
                {
                    //Log.d("Coming outo---454545--------------------==========","hjhjhj");
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (canvas.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth()) / 2, (canvas.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight()), null);
                    // mFps.draw(canvas, (canvas.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth()) / 2, 0);

                    mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
                bmp.recycle();
                }

            //FindFeatures(bitmapdata,j,i);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Finishing processing thread");
    }
    //   public native void FindFeatures(final byte[] bitmapdata,long m,int height,int width);
    public native int[] FindFeatures(long n,long m);
    static {
    //  Log.d("Coming hereeeeeee","Coming hereeeeeeeeeeeeee");
        System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");

    }

    public class Demo
    {
        int[] x;
        int[] y;
        int check=0;
        int cod=0;
    }
}
```

Modify DBUserAdapter constructor:

```
 public DBUserAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = ctx; 
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
        }
```

Comment: When I am trying to write this I am getting error likr this The method open() is undefined for the type SQLiteDatabase

Comment: YEs, I got your problem. Your open method is actually for class DBUserAdapater. You will need to use the object of that class. Can you paste the code where you are calling this function public long insert(byte[] photo, String date) ?

Comment: I have pastated the main activity you can find the methos in while loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16432/discussion-between-vendettadroid-and-user1522869)

Comment: Now I am getting this exception in dbUseradapter 09-08 10:36:47.867: E/AndroidRuntime(3862): java.lang.NullPointerException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)

Comment: Can we move to chat? it is not a good idea to have extended conversations here.

Answer (score 0):

DBHelper class is use for perform operation (create table , insert data , update data , delete data , read data)on database.

using following code create DBHelper class.

1.using following class you have to create database and table if database is available then don't overwrite the database and if database is available and table is not then create new table in database.

first you have to define .....

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final String DB_NAME = "Database_name";
private final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private final String TABLE_NAME = "Table_name";
private final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "id";
private final String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "name";
private final String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "basic_price";
private final String TABLE_ROW_THREE = "tax";
private final String TABLE_ROW_FOUR = "shipping";
private final String TABLE_ROW_FIVE = "price";
private final String TABLE_ROW_SIX = "image";
```

after defining variable you have to define following class in side DBHelper Class.

```
 private class CustomSQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        {
            public CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(Context context)
            {
                super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
            {
                String newTableQueryString = "create table " +
                                            TABLE_NAME +
                                            " (" +
                                            TABLE_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null," +
                                            TABLE_ROW_ONE + " text," +
                                            TABLE_ROW_TWO + " real," +
                                            TABLE_ROW_THREE + " real," +
                                            TABLE_ROW_FOUR + " real," +
                                            TABLE_ROW_FIVE + " real," +
                                            TABLE_ROW_SIX + " blob" +
                                            ");";
                    db.execSQL(newTableQueryString);


            }


            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

2.Create Constructor for DBHelper Class.

```
public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

3.Create following method for insert data into database.

```
public void insert_Row(String name, float basic_price, float tax, float shipping,float price,Bitmap image)
    {
        byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(image);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, name);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, basic_price);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_THREE, tax);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FOUR, shipping);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FIVE, price);
        values.put(TABLE_ROW_SIX, data);

        try
        {
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            Log.w("message","Insert successfully");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

4.Create Following method for updating data in to database.

```
 public void updateRow(long rowID,String name,float basic_price, float tax, float shipping,float price,Bitmap image)
                    {
                        byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(image);

                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, name);
                        values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, basic_price);
                        values.put(TABLE_ROW_THREE, tax);
                        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FOUR, shipping);
                        values.put(TABLE_ROW_FIVE, price);
                        values.put(TABLE_ROW_SIX, data);

                        try 
                        {
                            db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
                            Log.w("message","Update successfully";
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

5.Create Following method for delete data into database.

```
public void deleteRow(long rowID)
    {
        try 
        {
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID, null);
            Log.w("message","delete successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

6.Create following method for get particular row in to database.

```
 public void getRow(long rowID)
        {
            Cursor cursor;

            try
            {
                cursor = db.query
                (
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] { TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO, TABLE_ROW_THREE, TABLE_ROW_FOUR, TABLE_ROW_FIVE, TABLE_ROW_SIX },
                        TABLE_ROW_ID + "=" + rowID,
                        null, null, null, null, null
                );

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                {
                    do
                    {                   
                        String row_item_id=cursor.getLong(0);
                        String row_item_name=cursor.getString(1);
                        String row_item_basic_price=cursor.getFloat(2);
                        String row_item_tax=cursor.getFloat(3);
                        String row_item_shipping=cursor.getFloat(4);
                        String row_item_price=cursor.getFloat(5);
                        byte[] imgByte = cursor.getBlob(6);
                            Bitmap row_item_bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);

                    }

                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

7.create an ArrayList that will hold all the data collected from the database.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

This is a database call that creates a "cursor" object.
The cursor object store the information collected from the database and is used to iterate through the data.

```
 public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllRowsAsArrays()
        {

            ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();


            Cursor cursor;

            try
            {
                // ask the database object to create the cursor.
                cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[]{TABLE_ROW_ID, TABLE_ROW_ONE, TABLE_ROW_TWO},
                        null, null, null, null, null
                );

                // move the cursors pointer to position zero.
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                // if there is data after the current cursor position, add it
                // to the ArrayList.
                if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                        dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));

                        dataArrays.add(dataList);
                    }
                    // move the cursor's pointer up one position.
                    while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from
            // the database.
            return dataArrays;
        }
```